# How to show last taken image from specific folder?

Tags: android

I want to make a feature like default camera feature did.  There are a left thumbnail image which show last taken image. When click to the photo, it show the photo and I can slide to view next photo.

My photos is put on **"Abc/Pictures"** folder.

[image]

Comment: You want the latest photo or latest photo from "Abc/Pictures" folder?

Comment: @thealeksandr I want go get latest photo from "Abc/Pictures" folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the latest modified file in folder for specific extension

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.comparator.LastModifiedFileComparator;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.WildcardFileFilter;

...

    /* Get the newest file for a specific extension */
    public File getTheNewestFile(String filePath, String ext) {
        File theNewestFile = null;
        File dir = new File(filePath);
        FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*." + ext);
        File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);

        if (files.length > 0) {
            /** The newest file comes first **/
            Arrays.sort(files, LastModifiedFileComparator.LASTMODIFIED_REVERSE);
            theNewestFile = files[0];
        }

        return theNewestFile;
    }
```

**Addition**

To get all files or only png and jpeg use

```
new WildcardFileFilter("*.*");
new WildcardFileFilter(new String[]{"*.png", "*.jpg"});
```

Comment: @if the folder include both PNG and JPG files, how can I query all ?

Comment: Added how to get only images or all files

Comment: Hi thealeksandr, thank for your help. But I have a problem with child folder. Example I have two child folder of Abc folder as Abc/Pictures1 and Abc/Pictures2. How can I get lastest photo on folder from foder Pictures1 and Pictures2?

Comment: You can get the latest file in all child folders and then choose the latest one from them. Actually also if you are only the one who creates files in this folder you always can track the latest file. Each time when you creating a new file in this folders, save the path somewhere in SharedPreferences.  So you don't need to make this operation each time.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code find latest images from folder and I hope you are saving images with there time stamp which is standard appraoch.

```
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getPath() + "/Abc/Pictures"); 



    int imagesCount= path .listFiles().length; // get the list of images from folder
       Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdcardPath.listFiles()[imagesCount - 1].getAbsolutePath());
       eachImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp); // set bitmap in imageview
```

Comment: What is sdcardPath ?

Comment: this will find images inside "/Abc/Pictures" folder

Comment: from your code, it should change sdcardPath to path, right ?